# How to extract multiple queries at once in Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to do something like:

`var tab = r.db("test").table("test");
all =[
  tab.getAll('1').fitler({'hidden': false}).limit(1),
  tab.getAll('2').fitler('hidden': false}).limit(1),
  tab.getAll('3').fitler('hidden': false}).limit(1),
]`

But when running this query I'm getting:

```
Expected type DATUM but found SELECTION:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the "Expected type DATUM but found SELECTION" error can be solved by adding `.coerceTo('array')`:

```
var tab = r.db("test").table("test");
all =[
  tab.getAll('1').filter({'hidden': false}).limit(1).coerceTo('array'),
  tab.getAll('2').filter({'hidden': false}).limit(1).coerceTo('array'),
  tab.getAll('3').filter({'hidden': false}).limit(1).coerceTo('array')
]
```

But in this specific case, you can replace `.limit(1)` with `.nth(0)`:

```
var tab = r.db("test").table("test");
all =[
  tab.getAll('1').filter({'hidden': false}).nth(0),
  tab.getAll('2').filter({'hidden': false}).nth(0),
  tab.getAll('3').filter({'hidden': false}).nth(0)
]
```

Comment: Is it worth to do `.limit(1).nth(0)` together? In otherwords - does rethinkdb use the same optimisation for `nth` as for `limit` in this case?