# Can I get data as JSON string when I am listening updates from RethinkDB?

Tags: java, json, rethinkdb

```
Cursor changeCursor = r.table(Hardcoded.rethinkDBTableName()).changes().getField("new_val").without("id").run(conn);
    for (Object change : changeCursor) {
        System.out.println(change);
    }
```

**RESULT:**

```
{  
   askPrice=1.29846,
   symbol=EUR/USD,
   bidTime=1455800529000,
   askTime=1455800529000,
   bidSize=1,
   askSize=1,
   bidPrice=1.2984
}
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
{  
   "askSize":1,
   "askPrice":1.2978,
   "askTime":1455729430000,
   "bidTime":1455729430000,
   "bidPrice":1.29778,
   "symbol":"EUR/USD",
   "bidSize":1
}
```

Comment: Is actual result exactly the same in the block which is in your question ? I mean, is that starts with "{ " and ends with "}" or you added them when you are writing the question ?

Comment: @Bolzano yes, the result is exactly the same with {...}

Comment: I can get static data as JSON string in this way - r.table(TABLE_NAME).get(ID).toJson().run(conn), but when i'm listening updates with adding ".changes()" -  r.table(TABLE_NAME).changes().toJson().run(conn), it throw the exception - Expected type DATUM but found SEQUENCE: VALUE SEQUENCE

Comment: i assume toJson() method works with a single Data. its working because you are getting data with get(ID) , probably if you use get(ID) with changes() you'll get this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827952/how-to-extract-multiple-queries-at-once-in-rethinkdb, so this link can help you i guess

Comment: @Bolzano Thanks for the advice but adding coerceTo("array") throw the exception - Cannot call a terminal (`reduce`, `count`, etc.) on an infinite stream (such as a changefeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `r.table(Hardcoded.rethinkDBTableName()).changes().getField("new_val").without("id").map(val -> val.toJson())` and I think that will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It was very helpful for me. I resolved it on Java. Do you know how to do the same on Scala?

Comment: It should be the same trick except the anonymous function syntax inside the `map` will be whatever Scala's anonymous function syntax is.